# What is the reason that $zz^*$ is not written as $ |z|^2$ sometimes?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, packages, complex, feyncalc

For a general (complex) number $z$ I sometimes get terms that explicitly writes (for instance)

$$2zz^*+|z|^2. $$ I should add that these expressions come from long calculations involving packages (FeynCalc). How come `FullSimplify[]` does not simply put this expression to $3|z|^2$ instead?

Comment: `ComplexExpand` is intended for this sort of transformation. But it is a bit dull in this case and benefits from postprocessing by `Simplify`. `Simplify[ComplexExpand[z*Conjugate[z], z, TargetFunctions->{Abs,Arg}]]` gives the desired result.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau that was cool, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Running `FullSimplify` I get

```
FullSimplify[z Conjugate[z] + 2 Abs[z]^2]
```

> ```
> 3 z Conjugate[z]
> ```

This is actually more simple than `3 Abs[z]^2` in the eyes of `FullSimplify`. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) for more info.

```
Simplify`SimplifyCount[3 z Conjugate[z]]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

```
Simplify`SimplifyCount[3 Abs[z]^2]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Luckily there are many ways to guide `FullSimplify`. Here is one such way.

```
FullSimplify[z Conjugate[z] + 2 Abs[z]^2, ExcludedForms -> {_Abs}]
```

> ```
> 3 Abs[z]^2
> ```

### Edit

A more general way is to use a combination of `ComplexityFunction` and `TransformationFunctions`. Basically we'll assign a penalty whenever the unwanted pattern is present and teach `FullSimplify` the rule we want to use.

```
ToAbs[a_. z_ Conjugate[z_]] := a Abs[z]^2
ToAbs[e_] := e

FullSimplify[a1 Conjugate[a1] + a1 Conjugate[a1] + b1 Conjugate[b1], 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Conjugate, ∞] &), 
  TransformationFunctions -> {ToAbs, Automatic}
]
```

> ```
> 2 Abs[a1]^2 + Abs[b1]^2
> ```

Comment: OK thanks. let me try that.

Comment: When I write `FullSimplify[a1 Conjugate[a1] + a1 Conjugate[a1] + b1 Conjugate[b1], 
 ExcludedForms -> {_Abs}]` I get `Abs[b1]^2 + 2 a1 Conjugate[a1]`

Comment: Is there a simply way of telling Mathe to write everything in absolute bars? It just looks nicer that's all...

Comment: @Faq see my edit. Also you could try `TraditionalForm` to get the vertical bars.

Comment: Nice edit: This code you've written is then for FullSimplify everywhere (global, I would guess not)? I wonder how this affects computing time?

Comment: It will only work when you explicitly pass these options and I don't think there's much of a slowdown.

Comment: Oh ok I missed that these where options of `FullSimplify[]` Great!